# Why use router-outlet to access component of other module doesn't need add to export

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module, angular-compiler

I don't understand the difference between `router-outlet` and `module's exports array` compilation strategies.

- `router-outlet` will auto generate component by [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0cb4f12a7a57087ec4e8329a04d5dfc430764b45/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L124)
- if you are not use `router-outlet` to access component of other module, it will throw error from [template parser](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e0ed59e55f8740303fc93784548d81c2de210e7e/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L672)

[image]

**Why do we need to added it to exports array, Angular can't auto generate the component that defined in the module like `router-outlet`.**

---

I know if I want to use component of other modules, it's needed add to exports.

[live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-98xaxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fm1%2Fm1.module.ts)

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { M1Module } from './m1/m1.module';
// import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // AppRoutingModule,
    M1Module
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


----------------------

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    Comp1Component,
    Comp2Component
  ],
  exports: [
    Comp1Component
  ]
})
export class M1Module {}
```

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>


<app-comp1></app-comp1>
```

---

if I access the component through routing`(http://example.domain.com/comp1)`, it doesn't need to exports, it's can work.

[live example with routing](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbgswr)

```js
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { M1Module } from './m1/m1.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    M1Module
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

/*****************************************************/

import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { Comp1Component }   from './m1/comp1/comp1.component';
import { Comp2Component }   from './m1/comp2/comp2.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'comp1', component: Comp1Component },
  { path: 'comp2', component: Comp2Component }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}


/*****************************************************/

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Comp1Component } from './comp1/comp1.component';
import { Comp2Component } from './comp2/comp2.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [Comp1Component, Comp2Component],
})
export class M1Module { }
```

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<!-- it's need to use export -->
<!-- <app-comp1></app-comp1> -->

<!-- it doesn't need to use export -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

thanks, everyone's answer, it's summary that I understand :

**load component by module's exports array**

[image]

**load component by router**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [Angular NgModule FAQs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-should-i-export):

> **What should I export?**
>
> Export declarable classes that components in
>   other NgModules are able to reference in their templates. These are
>   your public classes. If you don't export a declarable class, it stays
>   private, visible only to other components declared in this NgModule.
>
> ...

> **What should I not export?**
>
> Don't export the following:
>
> Components that are only loaded dynamically by the router or by bootstrapping.
>   Such entry components can never be selected in another component's
>   template. While there's no harm in exporting them, there's also no
>   benefit.
>
> ...

Also note that router components are [automatically added](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components#a-routed-entry-component) to the `entryComponents` list.

Comment: thanks, I added two diagrams to describe my understanding, tell me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

**NgModule and scopes / visibility**
The confusion starts with components and services not having the same scope / visibility:

declarations / components are in local scope (private visibility),
providers / services are (generally) in global scope (public visibility).
It means the components you declared are only usable in the current module. If you need to use them outside, in other modules, you’ll have to export them:

But router-outlet load the particular component on run time so we don't need to export them.(Thats how i understood,pardon me if i'm wrong)

Comment: thanks, I added two diagrams to describe my understanding, tell me if I'm wrong