# Load component to router-outlet without declaring it in any module

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I just noticed that I can use a component without declaring in any module it as long as it has its own route. So, is it correct to remove all the directly routed components from the declarations array?
Is this new behavior in angular or maybe I just don't remember correctly.

You can see in my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-awaidv?file=src/app/cat/cat.component.ts) that the "cat" component is not declared but still loading on the button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895196/why-use-router-outlet-to-access-component-of-other-module-doesnt-need-add-to-ex)

Seems like: router-outlet will auto generate component by ComponentFactoryResolver

In other words below will throw error if you access without declaring:

```
<app-cats> </app-cats>
```

Comment: I also noticed that although the component will load it will not be able to use other components or directives if not included in the module that has access to those components or directives

Comment: So it means it only injects that component. Not dependencies.